# Sphinx Auto-documentation of Project

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm following a Sphinx tutorial for a python project and cannot seem to get the auto-created HTML file to put in the function doc-strings.

I followed the instructions on the getting started site [Sphinx Getting Started Guide](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro/getting-started-with-sphinx.html), and successfully created an HTML that had the basics (mostly empty).

Here is how my test-project is structured:

```
- /sphinx-test/
  -- doc/
  -- sphinx-test/
    --- __init__.py
    --- api.py
```

`__init__.py` is empty, and `api.py` has one function in it:

```py
def square_num(num):
    """Example function
    Args:
        num (float): A float to square.

    Returns:
        float: The squared number
    """
    return num**2
```

I navigated into the `doc/` directory and ran `$sphinx-quickstart`.

Here is how I answered the `$sphinx-quickstart` questions:

```
> Root path for the documentation [.]: 
> Separate source and build directories (y/n) [n]: y
> Name prefix for templates and static dir [_]: 
> Project name: sphinx_test
> Author name(s): nick
> Project version: 0.0.1
> Project release [0.0.1]: 
> Project language [en]: 
> Source file suffix [.rst]: 
> Name of your master document (without suffix) [index]: 
> Do you want to use the epub builder (y/n) [n]: 
> autodoc: automatically insert docstrings from modules (y/n) [n]: y
> doctest: automatically test code snippets in doctest blocks (y/n) [n]: y
> intersphinx: link between Sphinx documentation of different projects (y/n) [n]: n
> todo: write "todo" entries that can be shown or hidden on build (y/n) [n]: y
> coverage: checks for documentation coverage (y/n) [n]: y
> imgmath: include math, rendered as PNG or SVG images (y/n) [n]: n
> mathjax: include math, rendered in the browser by MathJax (y/n) [n]: n
> ifconfig: conditional inclusion of content based on config values (y/n) [n]: y
> viewcode: include links to the source code of documented Python objects (y/n) [n]: y
> githubpages: create .nojekyll file to publish the document on GitHub pages (y/n) [n]: n
> Create Makefile? (y/n) [y]: y
> Create Windows command file? (y/n) [y]: n
```

I made one change in the `conf.py` build file so that Sphinx can navigate up one directory to the project.  Here is the relevant lines in the `conf.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../'))
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.doctest',
    'sphinx.ext.todo',
    'sphinx.ext.coverage',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
]
templates_path = ['_templates']
source_suffix = '.rst'
master_doc = 'index'
project = u'sphinx_test'
copyright = u'2019, foobar'
author = u'foobar'
version = u'0.0.1'
release = u'0.0.1'
language = None
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']
pygments_style = 'sphinx'
todo_include_todos = True
html_theme = 'alabaster'
html_static_path = ['_static']
htmlhelp_basename = 'sphinx_testdoc'

latex_elements = {
}

latex_documents = [
    (master_doc, 'sphinx_test.tex', u'sphinx\\_test Documentation',
     u'foobar', 'manual'),
]

man_pages = [
    (master_doc, 'sphinx_test', u'sphinx_test Documentation',
     [author], 1)
]

texinfo_documents = [
    (master_doc, 'sphinx_test', u'sphinx_test Documentation',
     author, 'sphinx_test', 'One line description of project.',
     'Miscellaneous'),
]
```

I then ran `$make html`.

This generated an `index.html` file, as expected, but it does not contain any information on my `square_num()` docstring.  I have not edited any other `sphinx-quickstart` default file.

What should I do to get the doc-strings in the documentation?

EDIT:

This is not quite a duplicate of
[How to generate Python documentation using Sphinx with zero configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090894/how-to-generate-python-documentation-using-sphinx-with-zero-configuration)

The specific solutions in that question did not work. In line 3 of the `conf.py` I had already implemented that solution by adding the line: `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../'))`.  While the problem was the same, the solutions were slightly different.

The solution I found was to after that line:
`sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__name__), '..'))` (See answer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate Python documentation using Sphinx with zero configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090894/how-to-generate-python-documentation-using-sphinx-with-zero-configuration) See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15091333/2214933 See also http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html and http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html

Comment: Thank you, I have tried those solutions. Unfortunately they did not work.  I eventually found an answer as posted below.

Answer (score 0):

After a decent amount of trail and error, I found that editing the `conf.py` file as follows worked:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__name__), '..'))
```